# javascript: can't iterate over an array: getting : TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to iterate over roles for a business rule. But when i reach there, I get following error:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

Printing roles array on console:

```
console.log('role:' + role);
```

My array console result is as following:

```
 role:ROLE_TEAM_MANAGER,ROLE_SCORER,ROLE_LEAGUE_MANAGER
```

my loop:

```
for(var j=0;j<role.length;j++){

    var ccRole = role(0); // generates error
    or
    var ccRole = role(j); // generates error
    }
```

I have spent sometime on it, but don't know what's wrong here.

Comment: I recommend to read a [**JavaScript tutorial**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Referring_to_Array_Elements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct is, to access an element of an array like below:

```
arrayName[index]
```

where `arrayName` is the name of your array and `index` is the index of the element you want to get or set it's value.

Answer (score 1):

`role` is an array not a function.  Access the elements of `role` by using square brackets `[]` not parenthesis `()`.

```
for(var j=0;j<role.length;j++){
    var ccRole = role[j];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using brackets like `role(0)` try using square brackets like `role[0]`

More info about arrays at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp